# How to replace 20% random row values with 100 in python in a single column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython

How to replace 20% random row values with 100 in python in a single column(Rating) in dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) with `frac=0.2`. Then use `loc` to select those indices and replace their value with `100`:

```
# example dataframe
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[random.randint(1,10) for x in range(10)],
                   'Col2':[random.randint(1,10) for x in range(10)]})
print(df)

   Col1  Col2
0     1     3
1     1     6
2     3     9
3     9     5
4    10     4
5    10     2
6    10     7
7     4     5
8    10     7
9    10     9
```

```
idx = df['Col1'].sample(frac=0.2).index
df.loc[idx, 'Col1'] = 100

   Col1  Col2
0   100     3
1     1     6
2   100     9
3     9     5
4    10     4
5    10     2
6    10     7
7     4     5
8    10     7
9    10     9
```

Or to make it more general, without hardcoding `0.2` and `100`, here's a function which returns your desired dataframe:

```
def replace_sample(dataframe, column, fraction, val_replace):
    idx = dataframe[column].sample(frac=fraction).index
    dataframe.loc[idx, column] = val_replace

    return dataframe

replace_sample(df, 'Col1', 0.2, 100)

   Col1  Col2
0     2     5
1     5     1
2     4     3
3    10    10
4   100     5
5     6     7
6    10     1
7     8     8
8   100     9
9     2     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sample` and a `loc`:

```
l = df['Rating'].sample(int((20/len(df))*100)).tolist()
df.loc[df['Rating'].isin(l),'Rating'] = 100
print(df)
```

Comment: All are going to change value with 100

Comment: I am want to change only 20%